Double dual of a module and projectivity
Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be a left $R$-module. The dual $M^* = \mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)$ is a left $R$-module with respect to the right action
$
f.r(m) = mr.
$
for $m \in M$, $f \in M^*$, and $r \in R$. If we repeat the process and look at the dual of $M^*$ then we arrive back at a left module. In the case that $M$ is finitely generated and projective this module is canonically isomorphic to $M$. Can this happen for a larger class of module than projective?

Unser the term "reflexive module" you'll find many examples. I have closed this as a duplicate where this was explained. See the answers there in particular, also the linked MO question.
